# CanCan for shared view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using cancan for authorization. I have a shared view which need authorize depending on which controller it is.

The problem is:
I have shared partial (description.rhtml) and it is used by two different models (Product and Orders). So when some one go to

www.example.com/product/1 - description section shows description about product
www.example.com/order/1 - description section shows description about order

This description section has edit button on it so the user can edit it but the condition is

- the user must be owner of the product when on product/1 page or
- owner of order when user is on order/1 page.

My ability class check for

- if user is owner or not - depending on product or order controller
  However on view:

  ```
  if (can? :update, @orders) || (can? :update, @product)
  < hide edit button >
  end
  ```

  but if can? :update, @orders return true or false, it show or hides edit button depending on that condition only

So my question is how can make use CanCan to tackle this problem

Hope I was clear.

Comment: Also -- go back over your old questions and mark the correct answer. 43% is not an acceptable rate.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear....question is,  how can we use cancan for a view (partial) that is shared by two or more controller

Comment: @jesse - are you saying I marked 43% not acceptable answer?

Comment: @Viral -- I'm saying you've only accepted answers for 43% of the questions you've asked. That should be 100%.

Comment: @Jesse I have asked 12 question and from that 5 are unanswered, 1 i have answered and rest i have mark has accepted answered so it total 43%...I hope this is not stopping you to answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use the exact same partial for products and orders.

You might want to use a layout:

views/layouts/description.html.erb

```
<div class="description">
    <%= model.description %>
    <!-- other common code... -->
    <div class="actions">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

views/orders/description.html.erb

```
<%= render :layout => "layouts/description", :locals => { :model => @order } do %>
    <%= if (can? :update, @order) %>
       your link
    <% end %>
<%= end %>
```

You don't have to do that, but I think it's cleaner than having to deal with several models in the same partial.

---

side note:

`but if can? :update, @orders return true or false, it show or hides edit button depending on that condition only`

I don't really understand that. If @orders were null, then can? would return false, and the result of the whole expression would be the result of `(can? :update, @product)` which, I thought, was what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks robiin for response,...yeah `but if can? :update, @orders return true or false, it show or hides edit button depending on that condition only` I guess you are right...let me check my code for that...I guess I am return false so it not evaluating second condition.... thanks for the pointer